# react beautiful DnD not making me drag and drop

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have a `React` app where I'm using `react-beautiful-dnd` to implement a drag and drop feature. I have a list of `items` (image, button, and TextView) that I want to make draggable and droppable. I have defined a `handleDragEnd` function that I want to use to handle the dragged item, but I haven't implemented it yet.

The `Center` component contains the `DragDropContext` and the `Droppable` component which contains an unordered list. The `items` array is used to render each individual draggable component with the `Draggable` component.

Here's the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Item from "./Item";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";
import "react-beautiful-dnd/style.css";

const Center = () => {
  const items = ["image", "button", "TextView"];

  const handleDragEnd = (result) => {
    // TODO: Implement logic for handling the dragged item
  };

  return (
    <div className="Center">
      <DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleDragEnd}>
        <Droppable droppableId="droppable">
          {(provided) => (
            <ul
              className="items"
              {...provided.droppableProps}
              ref={provided.innerRef}
            >
              {items.map((item, index) => (
                <Draggable key={item} draggableId={item} index={index}>
                  {(provided) => (
                    <li
                      className="item"
                      ref={provided.innerRef}
                      {...provided.draggableProps}
                      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    >
                      <Item item={item} />
                    </li>
                  )}
                </Draggable>
              ))}
              {provided.placeholder}
            </ul>
          )}
        </Droppable>
      </DragDropContext>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Center;
// item is a component that display the items
```

Comment: I could not understand what you need, Can you make an example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new and also try to explain more what is your goal?

Comment: i dont know exactly what is the problem the code seems correct it works and when i refresh its not working anymore

Comment: Do you think you can make a dummy example in here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new? With the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the problem is very simple actually you only need to remove strict.mode from your index.js file in react